# Can I read From a Unordered_map while another thread is writing to that Unordered_Map? If no what might Be the Complications

Tags: c++, multithreading, thread-safety, c++14, unordered-map

Actually I have a unordered_map which acts like a cache. After a period of time the cache gets updated. By threads I am locking the map so that only one thread can write at a time. Is it fine to read from such a map while one of the thread is writing into it. If no What might be the Issues that i may face. I considered waiting till the thread finishes writing but it is degrading the application performance.

Comment: When you say "writing to that map" do you mean creating new entries in the map (i.e. modifying the map itself)? Or do you mean modifying existing entries (which doesn't modify the map itself)?

Comment: Its like Most of the time its will be Adding Entries. There are cases of deletion also. Only entry of new entries and deletion of entries.

Comment: The you must protect even reading from the map, as otherwise you could access the map in an incomplete state.

Comment: Its FIne if the data that is being written might not be available at that time but will i be able to read the existing one.

Comment: If the map is being modified to by another thread, it doesn't matter if it's adding elements or removing elements, it's in an *indeterminate* state until the modification is finished. You can't read (fetch elements) from a map (or any container) in an indeterminate state. You must have some kind of synchronization. Or perhaps do some research about *lock-less containers* (which are not part of the standard library though).